# Infinity video duration in UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I Was Making A brief search here in the forum , and related documentation class of 'UIImagePickerController' video duration. I still could not find a way to get the video duration forever ( or until space in the end device memory ) there is a maximum number should I put in the code below , or has no limits ?

```
videoRecorder.videoMaximumDuration = 9999999999;
```

And if I want the video duration lasts forever , I must put the number -1 ?

Comment: 10 minutes. No more. It´s the default value.

Comment: @OnikIV I have one more question for you!, Is possible to create my own video recorder using the framework AVFoundation, right? If I do that I have the same 10 minutes to record?

Comment: At first no, the device limits. Here you are:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureMovieFileOutput_Class/ And here is father information: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureFileOutput_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureFileOutput/maxRecordedDuration